# PHP Laravel Eloquent, foreach breaking my relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Consider this block of code:

```
$booking = Booking::where('id', $bookingId)->with('Trips.depFlight')->with('Trips.arrFlight')->first();

foreach($booking->trips as $trip){}

return response()->json($booking);
```

When the foreach runs, both arrFlight and depFlight are not returned as json
When the foreach does not run, both depFlight and arrFlight returned.

Why?

Comment: How are the relationships in your Booking and Trip models defined?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is because of case of your relationship. If you defined your relationship in your model `Trips` you should use this everywhere as `Trips` and not `trips`. so you should use it this way:

```
$booking = Booking::where('id', $bookingId)->with('Trips.depFlight')->with('Trips.arrFlight')->first();

foreach($booking->Trips as $trip){}
```

or

```
$booking = Booking::where('id', $bookingId)->with('trips.depFlight')->with('trips.arrFlight')->first();

foreach($booking->trips as $trip){}
```

depending of actual name of your relationship (with capital letter or not)

If you use in your code relationship with different letter case, Laravel will execute query one more time (performance loss) and probably in this case further relationships (`depFlight` and `arrFlight` are lost)